# unpacking arguments to a function if variable not empty

Tags: python, conditional-statements, argument-unpacking

I'm trying to pass in a list of arguments to function if the variable is not empty.

Here's the variable:

```
shape_properties: {
                    'header_shape': {
                                    'width': 8582400,
                                    'height': 468000
                                    },
                    'chart_shape': {
                                    'width': 8582400,
                                    'height': 3585600
                                    }}
```

But this variable could be None sometimes:

```
shape_properties=None
```

I would like to pull in the arguements from shape_properties if its not empty. Here is what I tried:

```
sub_title_shp = add_textbox(slide,
                            text=question_label,
                            **shape_properties['header_shape'] if shape_properties else '')
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: add_textbox() argument after ** must be a mapping, not unicode
```

The error code suggests to me that I cannot use **args in condition like this?

Here is what add_textbox() looks like:

```
def add_textbox(
          sld, text, 
          left=Emu(0), top=Emu(0), width=Emu(300), height=Emu(100),
          font_name="Calibri",
          font_size=12, 
          font_bold=True,
          font_italic=False,
          font_color=(89,89,89),
          font_color_brightness=0,
          font_color_theme=None,
          word_wrap=True, 
          auto_size=None, 
          fit_text=True,
          font_file=None,
          margin_left=0.25,
          margin_right=0.25,
          margin_top=0.13,
          margin_bottom=0.13, 
          vertical_alignment='top',
          horizontal_alignment='left',
          textbox_fill_solid=False,
          textbox_color=(100,0,0),
          textbox_color_brightness=0,
          ):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ;)

```
sub_title_shp = add_textbox(slide,
                        text=question_label,
                        **(shape_properties['header_shape'] if shape_properties else {}))
```

Comment: got another error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @Boosted_d16 that must be a problem when add_textbox doesn't get a parameter it needs, show full code in another question if you want...

Comment: add_textbox only needs two parameters, the rest are optional but it seems that the optional parameters's values are overwritten by the empty dict?

Comment: Got it working, you were right, there was a problem with add_textbox. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Boosted_d16    No problem :)